# Write conditional expression better

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have the following code

```
function x () { 
    return a ? (b ? 'result2' : 'result1') : 'result1';
}
```

Is there a better way to combine these two conditions into one?

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure this was closed because it's too generic and short to be from a project.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my question, I swapped the return result..

Comment: The reason why I rolled this back is that code in the question should not change after an answer is given.  Normally I'd suggest asking a new question, but such a question would likely be closed for the same reason as this one.  It's possible that this question might fit on another site in the stack exchange network.  Or you could ask a new question with sufficient context here.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends on how better is defined. There are several questions to address for an answer that would fit the desired solution.

Is a version without boolean operations better?

```
function x() {

    var toReturn = "result1";

    if ( a ) {
        if ( b ) {
            toReturn = "result2";
        }
    }
    
    return toReturn;
}
```

Is a version without a ternary operation and with an `or` logical operation better?

```
function x() {
    
    if ( !a || !b ) { return "result1"; }

    return "result2";
}
```

Is a version with a logical `and` and a ternary operation better?

```
function x() {
    
    return ( a && b ) ? "result2" : "result1";
}
```

Just to ilustrate how complex the question is. Since better is a vague term better look into it before choosing an alternative.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my question, I swapped the return result.. is there a way to write the new statement with ternary?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce this to a single expression with one ternary operator by using the [logical AND operator (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

```js
function x () {
    return a && b ? 'result2' : 'result1';
}
```

This provides the same output:

| a | b | return value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `true` | `true` | `result2` |
| `false` | `false` | `result1` |
| `false` | `true` | `result1` |
| `true` | `false` | `result1` |

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in my question, I swapped the return result.. is there a way to write the new statement with ternary?